# MOSS 2007: Changing the masterpage for one page layout

Tags: master-pages, sharepoint-2007, page-layout

In a MOSS server,  I would like a specific page layout to use the selected masterpage. Instead, i want this specific page layout to use a blank master page so i can use that page layout for pop message. I want to use a blank master page so that the my site's navigation menu, header and footer don't appear in my popup.

I found this blog post ([Change MasterPageFile for a specific PageLayout](http://mindsharpblogs.com/Aaron/archive/2008/02/26/4379.aspx)) which explains how to do this but it requires the page to be ghosted which cannot be in my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create your own page layout in Sharepoint Designer, in the attributes of the page you can specify a masterpage url, instead of using the keywords ~default.master or ~custom.master use your own master page (make sure its published and available or it will fail).